# Why does Visual Studio on Windows 10 crash with System.AccessViolationException?

Tags: windows-10, crash, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I've got a pretty basic Windows 10 box. Recently, Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 started crashing.

I've tried: installing Visual Studio 2013 update 5, Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, googling the error, going down ratholes like checking video card driver incompatibility, problematic settings in Visual Studio itself, permissions in the system %temp% folder, starting with various flags like /safemode and /resetsettings and /resetuserdata and am currently grasping at straws.

The symptoms are: Visual Studio starts, and either crashes as soon as the splash screen disappears, or crashes as soon as I try and do anything with a Solution (check project dependencies, build a project, let the welcome page load).

When I look at the Event Viewer, there is always an error, and the stack trace always indicates a System.AccessViolationException.

Here's a recent example:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Synchronize()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track.OnIsEnabledChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.Invoke(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsEnabledChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsEnabledChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(System.Windows.Media.Visual, System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateForceInheritPropertyOnChildren(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsEnabledChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.Invoke(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar.ViewChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.Invoke(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateDependents(System.Windows.Style, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, MS.Utility.FrugalStructList`1<System.Windows.ChildPropertyDependent> ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.OnTriggerSourcePropertyInvalidated(System.Windows.Style, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs, Boolean, MS.Utility.FrugalStructList`1<MS.Utility.ItemStructMap`1<System.Windows.TriggerSourceRecord>> ByRef, MS.Utility.FrugalMap ByRef, Int32)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyKey, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.OnLayoutUpdated(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext+InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Obviously something fundamental is wrong - this is a major product from a major software company on their flagship OS. I'm out of ideas tho.

If it matters, here's my machine config:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 4/4/2016, 18:51:18
             Machine name: CALCUTTA
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 10586) (10586.th2_release_sec.160223-1728)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
             System Model: System Product Name
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 11/04/10 14:27:40 Ver: 08.00.15
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU         550  @ 3.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
                   Memory: 4096MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 4088MB RAM
                Page File: 4829MB used, 2201MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
          DirectX Version: 11.3
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
       System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
                 Miracast: Not Available
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.10586.0000 64bit Unicode
```

Comment: Have you reinstalled these programs?

Comment: update the GPU drivers and disable HW acceleration in the VS options (if you can get VS running)

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I've done both these things, having seen them suggested elsewhere. No difference.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, multiple times, using both web install and standalone installers.

Comment: capture a dump of the crashing VS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx), create an issue on connect (connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/) and attach the dump there.